# Variável não é preenchida na procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor, procedure

Bom dia. Estou rodando a procedure abaixo, que valida se a carga deve rodar ou não, e caso não seja possível rodar, retorna uma mensagem de erro informando porque não rodou:

```
declare @dtAtual date,
        @dtCarga date,
        @hrAtual varchar(8),
        @stCarga varchar(20),
        @flPass bit = 0,
        @dtAtualizacaoYC date,
        @dsMensagemErro varchar(500)

select @dtCarga = max(DT_CARGA) from DBM_ETL..LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS
select @dtAtual = getdate()
select @dtAtualizacaoYC = MAX(dtCarga) from DBM_YC..ycFatosBoletos

if(@dtAtualizacaoYC < @dtAtual or @dtAtualizacaoYC is null)
begin

    if(@dtAtual = @dtCarga)
    BEGIN

        select @stCarga = STATUS_CARGA FROM LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS WITH(NOLOCK)
        where DT_CARGA = @dtCarga

        WHILE(@stCarga in ('EM ANDAMENTO','PROCESSANDO'))
        BEGIN

            select @hrAtual = CONVERT(varchar(8),convert(time,getdate()))

            if(@flPass = 0 and @hrAtual >= '12:00:00')
            begin       
                SET @dsMensagemErro = 'O processo está a muito tempo em execução e não há disponibilidade na tabela DBM_ETL.DBO.TMP_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS. Necessário verificar com o responsável pela atualização.'
                BREAK;
            end

            WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'

            select @stCarga = STATUS_CARGA FROM DBM_ETL..LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS WITH(NOLOCK)
            where DT_CARGA = @dtCarga

        END


        IF(@stCarga LIKE '%CONCLU[ÍI]DO%')
        BEGIN
            SET @flPass = 1
        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @dsMensagemErro = 'O status de processamento na tabela LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS foi atualizado, porém não está como "CONCLUÍDO". Status atualizado na tabela: '+@stCarga+''
        END                 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN       
        SET @dsMensagemErro = 'O processo de Carga da tabela TMP_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS não foi iniciado, ou o status de processo não foi inserido na tabela LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS'
    END


end

select @flPass as flPass, @dtCarga as dtCarga, @dsMensagemErro as dsMensagemErro
```

No caso, a tabela `LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS` está com `status_carga = CONCLUÍDO` e a data menor que a data atual.

Nesse caso, deveria cair no último `IF`, e exibir a mensagem:

> "O processo de Carga da tabela `TMP_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS` não foi
>   iniciado, ou o status de processo não foi inserido na tabela
>   `LOG_DISPONIBILIDADE_CARGA_CLIENTES_BOLETOS`"

No entanto a variável `dsMensagemErro` está vindo nula, não está exibindo mensagem nenhuma.

Alguém teria uma ideia de porque esta variável não está sendo preenchida, sendo que a *query* se encaixa nas condições do último `IF`?

EDIT: Já descobri o que era, galera. A variável dtAtualizacaoYC estava nula, pois o campo DT_CARGA da tabela DBM_YC..ycFatosBoletos estava nulo. Fiz um update e coloquei a DT_CARGA = data atual e foi. Comi bola. Obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: mas se `status_carga = CONCLUÍDO` não deveria cair no `if` e sair? a mensagem que você mencionou está no `else`

Comment: Além da observação acima do Ricardo, sempre que definir o valor de uma variável a partir de uma consulta deve-se verificar se ela recebeu algum valor ou não (NULL).